# Employee java program

Tags: java

So I've been trying to write a program and it requires me to use a bunch of methods and such but I'm still a beginner I was wondering what I'm suppose to do to make this happen.

 A static field, empCount, keeps track of the number of instantiated employees and can be retrieved using the `static` method `getCount( )`

he methods `getName( )` and `getNumber( )` return the employee's name and employee number respectively

 this is what I have now

```
public class Employee {

private static int empCount;
private String empName;
private double empSalary;
private double empRate;
private double empHour;
private double empBase;
private static int empPieces;
private static int empType;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    empCount = 0;
    empCount ++;

    System.out.printf("Enter Employee Name: " );
    String name =input.next();
    Employee e1= new Employee(name);
    System.out.printf( "Employee count is " + empCount+ "\n" );
    empCount ++;

    e1.setEmployeePay(253553);
     System.out.printf("Enter Employee Name: ");
    name =input.next();
    Employee e2= new Employee(name);
    System.out.println( "Employee count is " + empCount );
    empCount ++;

     System.out.printf("Enter Employee Name: ");
    name =input.next();
    Employee e3= new Employee(name);
    System.out.println( "Employee count is " + empCount );
    empCount ++;

     System.out.printf("Enter Employee Name: ");
    name =input.next();
    Employee e4= new Employee(name);
    System.out.println( "Employee count is " + empCount );
    empCount ++;

    System.out.println("Employee "+name+" earned: " +"");
    System.out.println("Employee "+name+" earned: " +"");
    System.out.println("Employee "+name+" earned: " +"");
    System.out.println("Employee "+name +" earned: " +"");
}

public Employee(String name){

}
public String getName(){

 return empName;    
 }
 public static int getNumber(){
 Random random = new Random(); 
     int empnumber = 1000 + random.nextInt(9999);

 return empnumber;
 }
```

Comment: What is your Question?

Comment: @ArunKumar I'm guessing it's the "what I'm suppose to do to make this happen".

Answer (score 1):

I notice that you increment the `empCount` variable in your main method each time a new instance of an `Employee` is created.

If you are trying to track the number of instances of `Employee` with the `empCount` variable, an easier approach would be to increment it in your constructor, ie:

```
public Employee(String name) 
{
    empName = name;
    empCount++; //Increment counter here to avoid redundant code
}
```

By adding the code to increment it to your constructor, you save yourself the trouble of having to rewrite the same code upon each instantiation of a new `Employee`.

Also, it would be easier to create a field for the `Employee`'s number, add the initialization code to your constructor, and just return it in your getter method for the number; you could even use the `empCount` variable to determine the number rather than the `Random` class, that way each instance of `Employee` has a unique identifier, whereas your current implementation could produce duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

It is good practice to keep your model in a separate class

```
import java.util.*;

public class emp
{
public static ArrayList<Employee> list=new ArrayList<Employee>();
public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);

    while(true){
        System.out.print("Enter Name : ");
        String name=s.nextLine();

        Employee e=new Employee(name);
        list.add(e);

        System.out.println("Count : " +list.size());

        for(Employee x:list){
            System.out.println("Employee : " +x.getName());
          }
    }

}

}


 class Employee{

 private String empName;
 private double empSalary;
 private double empRate;
 private double empHour;
 private double empBase;
 // any other properies


 Employee(String name){
 empName=name;  
 }

 public String getName(){
 return empName;    
 }
 public void setName(String name){
  empName=name;    
 }
 //any other getters and setters

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I see few mistakes here in your code : 

String name =input.next(); // you have declared "name" variable here
Employee e1= new Employee(name);

name =input.next(); // you are assigning a new String here
Employee e2= new Employee(name);

name =input.next(); // you are assigning new String again
Employee e3= new Employee(name);


// here you are trying to print "name" , which will print only last assigned value for "name" variable.

System.out.println("Employee "+name+" earned: " +"");
System.out.println("Employee "+name+" earned: " +"");
System.out.println("Employee "+name+" earned: " +"");
System.out.println("Employee "+name +" earned: " +"");

And last mistake is 

// your constructor has no definition inside whereas everytime you are calling 
Employee e2= new Employee(name);
//with name parameter

public Employee(String name){

}
```

//So, what you need to do is

since your object properties are private like

```
private String empName;
```

you need to have setter and getter property defined for this variable

```
public String getEmpName() {
    return this.empName;
}

public void setEmpName(String empName) {
    this.empName = empName;
}
```

or instead of setter method, you can set while creating instance,

```
public Employee(String name){
    this.empName = name;
}
```

Then, instead of

```
System.out.println("Employee "+name+" earned: " +"");
```

you can use,

```
System.out.println("Employee "+e1.getEmpName()+" earned: " +"");
```

And so on.

Comment: I tried to do as you suggested and it still appears as
Employee employee.Employee@7f787395 earned:

Comment: Your getEmpName() is returning an Employee object it seems. Check your method once. It should return String i.e employee name (empName) variable